# Difference between Gunicorn Threads and ThreadPoolExecutor() in Python

Tags: python, flask, python-multiprocessing, gunicorn, python-multithreading

I have a Flask app where I use ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) in it.
I use this pool of threads when I send API requests to 3rd parties, in order to work in an asynchronous fashion.

I deliver my app in production using Gunicron with this configuration set up:

```
ExecStart=/root/app_name/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:app_name.sock -m 007 --timeout 180 main:app
```

Pay attention I DO NOT set up any thread in Gunicron, for example:
`gunicorn --workers=5 --threads=4 main:app`
My question is:

1. What's the difference between opening pool of threads in python Vs configure them in Guincron?
2. Should I also set the number of threads I open in the pool in the Gunicron config? my thread in code will be ignored if I do not do that?